# How to Capture the API's ?if API's have no end points and just showing baseUrls

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I need help or any suggestion. I have no idea how to do it?
Request URL: https://www.vizofly.com/NTU/Stress/StreamingAssets/Schools.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200  (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 172.66.43.59:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 6d4c32aacdb1926d-FRA
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 28 Jan 2022 18:14:00 GMT
etag: W/"1261-61f2caaf-3e2d8e;;;"
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
last-modified: Thu, 27 Jan 2022 16:39:11 GMT
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v3?s=aVZAHndifoZtrY0MH3O1WlauF71saxbdUuS7eBS0tReoUi5fGDG3zSlxFCTvbIwJxvGeVeiQyjT%2FVIUWKfUpxNbRT1jUi%2F9VEOvJnaBBRtJKapsW8RBKeLUxqP%2FusLzYEHQ%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.ntu.edu.sg

Comment: Ask is ambiguous. Title says API is hidden and in the body HTTP Response code is 200. If you can hit this api through postman from your load test rig then there should not be any issues

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about how to configure JMeter to send the request:

0. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test plan
1. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and set it up like:

   [image]
2. You may also want to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to represent browser [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to automatically handle [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and so on in order to [configure JMeter to behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)